# If $f(0)=2$, $f'(0)=3$ and $g=f^{-1}$ then what is the value of $g'(2)$?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I know that $f(0)=2$, $f'(0)=3$ and $g=f^{-1}$.

But how can I find the value of $g'(2)$?

Comment: You can write $f(x)=h(x)+3x+2$ for any $h$ such that $h(0)=h'(0)=0$. Then just fill in some different functions for $h$ for example $h=0$ or $h=x^3$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You have:
$g(f(x))=x$

Differentiate both sides:
$g' (f(x)) f'(x)=1$
Put $x=0$
$g' (f(0)) f'(0) =1$
Therefore,$ g'(2)= 1/3$

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $g \circ f = Id$, and derive both sides in 0, you get:
$$
f'(0) \cdot g'(f(0)) = 1 \\
\textrm{thus }g'(f(0)) = \frac{1}{f'(0)}
$$
Hence, $g'(2) = \frac{1}{3}$ .

Btw that's how you get the derivative of a reciprocal function in general.